# Which metals with high density do not react with mercury?

Tags: metal

I would like to know the highest density material between 10-17 g/mol range that is less than mercury and does not react with mercury.

Also would I like to know the highest density metal that is in solid form naturally.

Which ones are easily available and are highly dense?

Comment: 1) Iron is not smelted by mercury (it's ~8 g/ml). Not sure about 10-17 g/ml. 2) The mosts are Iridium and Osmium. The most easily available is lead, though it requires some caution when used.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a link](http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/Density.v.html) to a chart of all the elements in the Periodic table and their densities.  Iridium at $22.65~\mathrm{g/cm^3}$ is the densest of all the elements with Osmium a close second at $22.61~\mathrm{g/cm^3}$.  Sigma-Aldrich sells both of these metals (Iridium \$126.50 for 0.5 gram; Osmium \$195 for 1 gram).

> the highest density material between 10 17 range that is less than
>   mercury and does not react with mercury

Mercury has a density of $13.534~\mathrm{g/cm^3}$.  It sounds like you're asking for something with a density right below mercury that doesn't react with mercury. Rhodium at $12.45~\mathrm{g/cm^3}$ is probably the most readily available element with a density less than mercury.  As to rhodium's reaction with mercury, [an alloy is formed at 175 C](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010174412608#page-1).  If you're working at room temperature, especially for shorter periods of time (like hours) you'd probably be OK, but it really depends on your specific application.

Comment: Note: don't even think about buying osmium, the bastard oxidizes on air producing toxic vapors of tetroxide.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.
I see rhodium is highly expensive 
Rhodium costs Price 1g= $70,10g= $490 >

Yeah,Osmium is also more dense.
Oxidization on air- Thanks for the info.